# Delay a transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Is it possible to delay a transaction in one contract?

let's say Alice wants to send a product to Bob and Bob has to transfer, for example, 2 Ethers to Alice for buying that product.

How can I do this simultaneously? Can I delay transferring Ether and wait for receiving the imaginary tracking number or any other ways of approvements that Bob will have the product? Is it possible to do it with solidity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with an escrow smart contract. I wont go into detail because there is a good article here: https://medium.com/coinmonks/escrow-service-as-a-smart-contract-the-business-logic-5b678ebe1955. The logic is just like you say it delay until both Bob and Alice approve but in the beginning both of them have to pay double the amount of product to ensure one of them doesnt lie